# json_decode - associative arrays

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to store the value of `ok` in a variable starting from a json file but the output isn't what I'm expecting it to be.
Here's my code:

```
$messaggio = '{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request"}';
$messaggio = json_decode($messaggio, true);
print_r($messaggio);
```

Output: `Array ( [ok] => [error_code] => 400 [description] => Bad Request)`

Shoudn't it be like this? `Array ( [ok] => false [error_code] => 400 [description] => Bad Request)`
And if it shouldn't, how can I store the value of `ok` in a variable?

Comment: Try `var_dump`.

Comment: It returns me this `array(3) { ["ok"]=> bool(false) ["error_code"]=> int(400) ["description"]=> string(34) "Bad Request" }`, how to store it?

Comment: What do you mean by `store` it? Its strored in your `$messaggio` variable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to access to the value of `ok`

Comment: `$messaggio["ok"]`?

Comment: A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values. [Why does this false value convert to empty string instead of 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858771/why-does-this-false-value-convert-to-empty-string-instead-of-0)

Comment: My advice is to use 0 or 1, because Booleans behave unexpectedly when using Ajax for example.

Comment: @ITgoldman How do they "behave unexpected with AJAX"?! Especially when properly going through JSON, they behave very predictably…

Comment: @deceze Not sure I remember. But I had issues with jQuery ajax and boolean values, trying to send an `object`. I had to finally convert to JSON. so It's not like I said. sorry. Still it has potentially some issues when in some situation `false` becomes `"false"`.

Comment: @ITgoldman That only happens if you don't treat your data properly. Booleans don't randomly turn into strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of a script copied here and pasted in a php script:

```php
$messaggio = '{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request"}';
$messaggio = json_decode($messaggio, true);
print_r($messaggio);
var_export($messaggio['ok']);
```

As you can see, ... I've added var_export function to export the value.

```php
Array
(
    [ok] =>
    [error_code] => 400
    [description] => Bad Request
)
false
```

If you see nothing, it doesn't means that there is nothing.

I've also tried to show you a little example with interactive shell.

```bash
php -a
Interactive shell

php > $variabile = false;
php > echo $variabile;
php > var_export($variabile);
false
```

If you want to go deep into the content of a variable. Use var_export or var_dump functions.